# Overloading new and delete operator

Tags: c++

In the following code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void* operator new(size_t sz)    
{
   printf("operator new: %d Bytes\n", sz);  //LINE0
   void* m = malloc(sz);
   if(!m) puts("out of memory");
   return m;
}

void operator delete(void* m) {
   puts("operator delete");
   free(m);
}

class S {
    int i[100];
public:
    S() { puts("S::S()"); }
   ~S() { puts("S::~S()"); }
};

int main() {
  puts("creating & destroying an int");
  int* p = new int(47);   //LINE1
  delete p;
  puts("creating & destroying an s");
  S* s = new S;           //LINE2
  delete s;
  puts("creating & destroying S[3]");
  S* sa = new S[3];
  delete []sa;
}
```

Below is the output of the code:

```
creating & destroying an int
operator new: 4 Bytes
operator delete
creating & destroying an s
operator new: 400 Bytes
S::S()
S::~S()
operator delete
creating & destroying S[3]
operator new: 1208 Bytes
    S::S()
    S::S()
    S::S()
    S::~S()
    S::~S()
    S::~S()
    operator delete
```

LINE1 passes argument "47" to the operator new. Why at LINE0, it becomes 4 Bytes?
LINE2 does not pass a size argument to the operator new. Why the sz becomes 400 as printed at LINE0?

Comment: Because on your platform, one `int` is 4 bytes, and a struct of 100 `int`s is 400 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break down some of your code first.

- `int(47)` creates an integer with a *value* of 47.
- `operator new(size)` simply allocates `size` bytes to be used and returns a pointer to that new memory space

When you're calling `new int(47)`, you're *implicitly* calling `operator new(sizeof(int))->int(47)` - meaning that, since the output is `4`, `int` is 4 bytes on your system.

Similarly, when you call `new S`, you're implicitly calling `operator new(sizeof(S))->S()`. Since `S` contains 100 `int`'s, and each `int` is 4 bytes on your platform, you can now deduce that the `sizeof(S)` will be 400, which explains your output.

Comment: do you mean `operator new(sizeof (int))->int(47)`, that is, call the allocation function `operator new` with a size argument, and on the resulting memory location, call the `int` constructor with an argument of `47` ?  The snippet you gave, `new (sizeof(int)) int(47)`, would call a two-parameter allocation function.

Comment: After the operator new is overloaded, how to call the default new operator of C++? `std::new`?

Comment: @John: It is `::operator new(bytecount)`

Answer (score 1):

You are not understanding this right. Your `LINE1` does *not* "pass 47 to `operator new`". Rather, it passes `sizeof(int)` to `operator new`, and then creates an integer with value 47 in that memory.

Similarly, the code at `LINE2` calls `operator new` with `sizeof(S)`.

---

If you like the analogy, the statement `T * p = new T(a, b, c);` is roughly equivalent to this:

```
void * addr = operator new(sizeof(T));   // or T::operator new if available
T * p = new (addr) T(a, b, c);           // placement-new
```

In this analogy, `delete p;` has the following effect:

```
p->~T();
operator delete(addr);
```

Comment: For `T * p = new T(a, b, c);`, What are "a, b, c"? function arguments?

Comment: @John: Just some arbitrary constructor arguments for the sake of example.

Answer (score 0):

> Why at LINE0, it becomes 4 Bytes

because size of `int` is 4 bytes on this machine. The actual value of this integer, the 47 doesn't matter, the same size of 4 bytes will be allocated for any value of integer. The value 47 is used to initialize allocated memory.

```
LINE2 does not pass a size argument to the operator new(...)
```

the size of class S is visible to the compiler and it is passed implicitly as the first argument to the `operator new`. It is 400 because an array

```
int i[100];
```

contains 100 integers.

Answer (score 0):

LINE1 "int* p = new int(47)" allocates one int element, that is, 4 bytes. 47 is the initial value of the allocated int element. If you mean to allocate an array, you should do "int *p = new int[47]", and the delete command would be "delete[] p".

LINE2 allocates one S object. Because S object contains an int array of 100 elements, its size is 100 * 4 = 400.